# Using loop to create new struct in C

Tags: c, loops, struct

Here, I have created a structure of student having name, roll no, marks, etc as their members. So, what I wanted to do was create a new struct every time it iterates through a loop and saving data in it as it loops through.

So, I created a variable `stdname` that changes it's value every iteration and use it as a way to name a new student but it's not working. I am fairly new to C and I don't know what is wrong with my code here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Marks

{
    int phy;
    int chem;
    int math;
};

struct Student{
    char name[50];
    int rollN0;
    char remarks[100];
    struct Marks marks;
};

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        char stdname[50];
        sprintf(stdname,"student%d",i+1);
        struct Student stdname;
        printf("Enter the following data of Student No. %d:\n", i+1); 
        //taking data from user and storing 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem more clearly.  _"It's not working"_ is beyond unhelpful.  One issue I can see immediately is that you have redefined the `char` array named `stdname` with a struct using the same identifier.  The C language does not allow this.  The compiler should have issued an error message referencing that line of code, with a message something along the lines of "redefinition".  It's trying to point out the error so you can fix it.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: If this is a practice or homework assignment, please [edit] your post to include the full description.  In any case, you need to tell us what you think is wrong with the program. Post the inputs you tested it with, expected outputs and the actual results.

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur.

Comment: `"24:24: error: conflicting types for ‘stdname’"`

Comment: You can't declare the same variable name twice with two different types.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to solve your problem by implementing a systeme of linked list or tabs. I personnaly perfere linked list because when your code will evolute it's going to be easier to used the list in my pov.

So in the code you will see in your structure i add a `next` pointer this one will store the adresse of another student, if next is `NULL` then we can affirm there is no more student and we can stop crawling throught the list.

the function add use this principe; she goes to the tail of the list then replace the `next` with the adresse of the new student structure. And because the next of the new structure is `NULL` this process it re-usable

The function `create_new_node` is only data initation and memory allocation.
It looks very ugly because i don't realy know what you want store.

❗ **I didn't test this code and it's not optimised at all** ❗

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc function

struct Marks

{
    int phy;
    int chem;
    int math;
};

struct Student{
    char name[50];
    int rollN0;
    char remarks[100];
    struct Marks marks;
    struct Student* next;  // I had this
};
/// new ///
void add_node_to_list(struct Student* node, struct Student* list)
{
    while (list->next != NULL)
        list = list->next;
    list->next = node;
}

struct Student* create_new_node(struct Student data)
{
    struct Student* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Marks));

    if (!new_node)
        return NULL;

    new_node->name = data.name;
    new_node->rollN0 = data.rollN0;
    new_node->remarks = data.remarks;
    new_node->marks = data.marks;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    return new_node;
}
/// end-new ///

int main(void /* new */)
{
    struct Student* list = NULL;
    struct Student* new_node = NULL;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        char stdname[50];
        sprintf(stdname,"student%d",i+1);
        /// new ///
        if (!list) {                        // first the first element
            list = create_new_node((struct Marks) {stdname, 0, "\0", {0, 0, 0}, NULL}); 
            if (!list)        // check for malloc errors
                return 1;
        } else {                            // every time there is a new student
            new_node = create_new_node((struct Marks) {stdname, 0, "\0", {0, 0, 0}, NULL});
            if (!new_node)  // check for malloc errors
                return 1;
            add_node_to_list(new_node, list);
        }
        /// end-new ///
        printf("Enter the following data of Student No. %d:\n", i+1);
        //taking data from user and storing
    }
    return 0; // new: your main should always return a value. Compile with W flags see: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html
}
```

Here is my propostion,
Notice me if i had been clumsy, i'm a new user on stack.

Also feel free to ask question or fix my own error

Hope I helped you